# Instagram Authentication after March 31, 2020

Tags: api, authorization, instagram, legacy

As i see at https://www.instagram.com/developer/

> on March 31, 2020. As of March 31, 2020, all Legacy API capabilities
> will be fulfilled by the Instagram Graph API and the Instagram Basic
> Display API .

and at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

> API Instagram Basic Display is not for authentication

**1.** is no longer any way to authenticate users by Instagram? if i need only identify and take instagram_id from user, no more?!

**2** Is "Legacy API" is only `https://api.instagram.com/v1/...` ? and not all of `https://api.instagram.com/...` ? because i see at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/ :

> ### Base URLs
>
> 1. api.instagram.com — for getting Instagram User Access Tokens
> 2. graph.instagram.com — for getting Instagram user profiles and media

**3** Will documentation pages starts at `https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/` will completele removed after March 31, 2020 ??

**4** Is only way to save users, previously uses instagram-authentication, is create new auth-way (create pass for example) to save them?

Comment: Have you solved this ? Can you still login via instagram ?